# Callback function Jquery/javascript returning an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I dont know if i'm doing this the wrong way but I can't think of another way to do it.

I have a function in php that i'm calling with $.post and I want it to return an array.  It sounds like I need to use a callback function and i'm trying but it just wont work.

Here is the code:

Jquery:

```
$("#e_del_date_btn").click(function(){
    var new_date = $("#edited_del_date").val();
    if (new_date == '') {new_date = $("#edited_del_date").attr("placeholder");}
    var new_time = $("#edited_del_time").val();
    var non = $("#non").html();
    function getarray(new_date, new_time, non, callback) {
        $.post('http://localhost:8080/wsad2/post.php',{'new_date':new_date,'new_time':new_time,'non':non}, function(data) {
            callback(data);
        });
    }
    getarray(new_date,new_time,non, function(data) {
        alert(data[0]);
        $("#odi_span").html(data[0]);
        $("#e_del_date_pencil").attr("value",data[1]);
        $("#e_del_date_pencil").attr("value2",data[2]);
    });
    $("#e_del_date").hide();
    $("#e_del_date").css("z-index","0");
    $("#po_main_div_test").css({ opacity : 1.0 });
});
```

PHP Code:

```
$returndata = array();
$returndate = $returntime = $returntext = '';

if ($fail == "false") {if ($row['complete'] == "no") {$returntext .= '(When Completed) ';}}
$returntext .= 'This order is scheduled to be delivered on<br>';
if ($fail == "false") {$returntext .= $new_date_2;$returndate = $new_date_2;} else {$returntext .= $orig_deldate;$returndate = $orig_deldate;}
$returntext .= ' between ';
if ($fail == "false") {$returntext .= $new_time_2;$returntime = $new_time_2;} else {$returntext .= $orig_time;$returntime = $orig_time;}
if ($fail == "true") {$returntext .= '<br>The New Delivery Date must be tomorrow or later.';}

$returndata[0] = $returntext; 
$returndata[1] = $returndate; 
$returndata[2] = $returntime; 

//echo ($returntext);

return $returndata;
```

from some of the things I've read I might be trying to use $.post improperly, but basically I need to pass the date/time variables and then have the php return the value but they can be changed in the PHP code (which is the point of this, to edit a delivery date/time) so i need the value sent from the php back to the JavaScript in case it was changed, so i can update the attribute in case they decide to change it again w/out refreshing the page.

My problem is, the alert is always blank (the alert is for testing purposes) and basically it SEEMS to be working, but the 3 jquery calls in the getarray() function do not seem to be firing, or if they are they aren't working.  right now the HTML field i'm updating doesn't change no matter what I do.

am I using the callback function improperly?  I really need $.post to return an array, not just echo data so that I can update multiple fields instead of just one.

Also, i've left out some of the php code as I didn't think it was relevant.  i just wanted to show the creation of the array and it being filled with data.

Comment: you aren't printing anything by using `return $returndata` , try `echo json_encode($returndata);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to print the data from your PHP code as a JSON (JavaScript) array. Then use JSON.parse() in your JavaScript code to parse the text and turn it into an array.

Comment: the json_encode echo with a JSON.parse solution worked great.  Took me a bit to figure it out exactly but i got a working version.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can echo an array with PHP with JSON:

PHP:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Javascript:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Furthermore: How to send a proper POST request with JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "test.php",
   data: {my_$_Post1: "value"}
}).done(function() {
   //whatever you want to do
});
```

Or(***NOT RECOMMANDED***):

```
Answer = $.ajax({
   url: "test.php",
   async: false
   data: {my_$_Post1: "value"}
});
alert(Answer);
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: `async: false` is pretty much NEVER recommended as it just locks up the browser during the ajax call and is not a good design pattern for browser/javascript development.